# Pull out second url from string via regex

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way within PHP to pull the second link `http://secure.hello.com` out of the following string via regex.

```
http://hello.com/http://secure.hello.com
```

The string may or may not contain `https` in either of the spots.

Comment: Could there be something like this: `http://hello.com/http://secure.hello.com/http://supersecure.hello.com`? What should the output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
://\S*/(\w+://\S*)
```

It searches for the first `://` then searches for a slash followed by some word characters, then `://`, then anything apart from spaces. The text you want is in the first capturing group.

In a PHP string literal it can be written as:

```
'#://\S*/(\w+://\S*)#'
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/IpeP6)

If you want to restrict to http or https, change the `\w+` to `https?`.

Comment: The greedy .* inside the capturing group will also assume that everything else after that url is part of it. Perhaps you should amend it to any character not a space or something similar? `"#://.*/(\w+://[^\s])#"` Obviously this assumes that there could be something after the URLs which the OP hasn't specified.